# determine how many times the db is hit when a page is loaded

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm using .net(mvc) and ms sql server for my site.

I'd like to know how many times the db is hit when a page is hit?

is there a nice easy way to determine this?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "mssql" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1):

use SQL Server Profiler. 
And filter connections if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This probably wouldn't be practical at the SQL server level as in .net, connections can be reused unless you isolate this to a test system.

Therefore, a simple suggestion is to create a int counter in your model (I presume where you are calling your SQL queries) and increment the counter after each statement.  Then you can add this to your view (maybe using an HTML comment <!-- --> )  Of course, this assumes you have the source code and can make changes.